# Relation between injectivity and uniqueness

Tags: linear-algebra

Could you help me to clarify the following. I have some bijective operator $A:X\to Y$ and equation $Ax=b$ to be solved for $x$. Now I apply another operator $B:Y\to Z$ and get $Cx=c$, where $C=BA,c=Bb$. I have knowledge of the fact $Ax=b$ if and only if $Cx=c$. Can I claim that $Cx=c$ has unique solution? Is $C$ injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $B$ is the zero map. Then $Cx = C$ has many solutions in general.

So: no, and no.

If $B$ is not the zero map, but instead has a nontrivial kernel, the same kind of thing can still happen. As long as the vector $b$ is in the kernel of $B$, your problem becomes $Cx = 0$, and now as long as the image of $A$ intersects the kernel of $B$ nontrivially, you'll have multiple solutions to that equation.

**Post-comment addition**

Since I wrote my answer, you've added the constraint that you know that $Ax = b$ iff $Cx = c$.

Let's first work through what you know. Since $A$ is a bijection,

- $Ax = b$ has a unique solution. (Otherwise $A$ would not be injective).

You also know that

- $u$ is a solution to $Ax = b$, i.e. $Au = b$ if and only if $u$ is a solution to $Cx = Bb$, i.e., $Cu = Bb$.

Since $Ax = b$ has a solution, you know that

- $Cx = Bb$ has a solution, say $x_1$.

Suppose that $Cx_2 = Bb$ were a *different* solution. Then by the second 
item, you know that $Ax_2 = b$. Since $Ax_1 = Ax_2$ and $A$ is injective, you know that $x_1 = x_2$. This contradicts the hypothesis that $X_2$ is a different solution. Hence there's only one solution.

On to the final question: is $C$ injective?

Yes. For suppose that $a$ and $b$ are distinct, but $Ca = Cb$, then $C(a-b) = 0$. Letting $v = a-b$ (which is nonzero!), you get that

$$Cx_1 = Bb$$
above, but what happens if we apply $C$ to $x_1 + v \ne x_1$? We get
\begin{align}
C(x_1 + v) 
&= Cx_1 + Cv \\ 
&= Cx_1 + 0 \\ 
&= Bb 
\end{align}
and in this case, we find that there are two solutions, $x_1$ and $x_1 + u$, to the equation 
$$
Cx = Bb
$$
while there's only one solution to $Ax = b$, namely $x_1$. This contradicts the second bullet, so our assumption that $C$ is not injective must be false.

Comment: I'm confused by the following fact: I know that $Ax=b\iff Cx=c$ for this particular problem. Suppose that $x_1,x_2$ solve $Cx=c$, then, they should solve $Ax=b$, which contradicts to the fact that $A$ is injective. So it seems that solution to $Cx=c$ is unique. However, I can't connect the fact that $Ax=b\iff Cx=c$ to the injectivity of $C$.

Comment: See post-comment remarks in the original solution.